# Calling stored procedure within cursor - performance

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures, cursor, sybase

**CASE 1:**

> Call a stored procedure (say **sp**) again and again (say 50 times) in a while loop within a cursor.

```
while (i<50)
begin
call sp
i = i+1
end
```

**CASE 2:**

> Write logic of **sp** directly within while loop within cursor.

```
while (i<50)
begin
/*do calculations (no call to any stored procedure)*/
i = i+1
end
```

In which case the performance will be better?

**EDIT 1:**

Logic of  **sp** is as below:

```
SELECT 
    @myDate = CASE  WHEN @val = 'A' 
                        THEN DATEADD (DY,1,@anotherDate)
                    WHEN @val = 'B'
                        THEN @someDate
                 END

/* Another stored procedure call */
EXEC someProc @myDate, @isXXX output

IF  (@isXXX>0)
BEGIN
    IF (@val = 'A')
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Flag='Y1'
    END
    ELSE 
    IF (@val = 'B') 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Flag='Y2'
    END
END  
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @Flag='N'    
END
```

Comment: Generally, you want to avoid use of `CURSOR` or `WHILE` loop. If you post the SP, we may rewrite to set-based fashion.

Comment: @FelixPamittan: Added the body of 'sp'. i think it can't be changed to set-based instructions.